# primefaces p:textEditor tab/keyboard navigation doesn't focus the next UI component

Tags: primefaces, quill, keyboard-navigation

We are using p:textEditor (based on quill editor) in our application and we have more UI components below p:textEditor. The problem is for accessibility, the user need to tab through the components in the page using keyboard; but when it comes to p:textEditor a tab acts as adding a tab(4 spaces).

The primefaces showcase [here](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/textEditor.xhtml) also has the same problem, how can we navigate to the submit button from p:textEditor using keyboard?

Comment: Then check how to disable the tab key in quill editor. That is what PF uses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Kukeltje, I disabled the tab key in quill editor.

For anyone who wants to do the same, you have to edit the texteditor.js file under META-INF/resources/primefaces/texteditor/ (when you reverse engineer the primefaces-version.jar (version=6.1 in my case)) and add the below code in render: function()

`_render: function() {
    ...
    this.cfg.modules = {
        toolbar: PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(this.id + '_toolbar'),
            keyboard: {
                bindings: {
                    tab: {
                      key: 9,
                      handler: function() {
                        // do nothing
                        return true;
                      } 
                    },
                    'remove tab': {
                      key: 9,
                      shiftKey: true,
                      collapsed: true,
                      prefix: /\t$/,
                      handler: function() {
                        // do nothing
                        return true;
                      }
                    }
                }
            }
    };
    ...
}`

For anyone who wants additional key customization can use the [Quill Interactive Playground](https://quilljs.com/playground/) to validate your changes.